# jQuery animate working in fiddle but not smooth online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a sort of accordion with three expanding divs (`#a`, `#b`, `#c`) in fiddle, but when I save it locally and open it in a browser the transitions are no longer smooth. I noticed specifically after clicking `#b` with `#a` expanded. I've included the HTML that references the CSS and JavaScript code. What's the cause and what is the best way to solve it?

```
<head>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="inner" id="a">1</div> 
                <div class="inner" id="b">2</div> 
                <div class="inner" id="c">3</div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="accordion.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/3794/

It seems like it only happens when either `#a` is expanded and `#b` or `#c` are clicked or `#b` is expanded and `#c` is clicked.

Comment: Personally, I'd ditch jquery and do the actual animation with CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/zey3Lok7/ - you can almost do away with javascript altogether - http://jsfiddle.net/zey3Lok7/1/

Comment: your code is working. only the issue is that when you copy it from fiddle, not all things are copied. see the answere that i have given below http://stackoverflow.com/a/33408930/4944490

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using single `click` event handler for animations with `.animate()` `easings` property set to `"linear"`, `css` `transition` for effects, set `width` of `.middle div` elements to `33%`

```js
$(".middle div").click(function() {

  $(this).siblings().animate({
    width: "10%",
    opacity: 0.6
  }, 0, "linear");
 
  $(this).animate({
    width: "80%",
    opacity: 1
  }, 0, "linear");
  
});
```

```css
div.inner {
  max-width: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.outer {
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div.middle {
  display: table-row;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
#a {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
#b {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#c {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#a,
#b,
#c {
  transition: width 500ms, opacity 500ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="inner" id="a">1</div>
      <div class="inner" id="b">2</div>
      <div class="inner" id="c">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/3798/

Comment: This seems to have the same problem on the initial click rather then when one is expanded, when I run it locally

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
window.onload = function() {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.inner'), function(el) {
      el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        this.parentElement.className = 'middle ' + this.id;
      });
    });

  } //]]>
```

```css
div.inner {
  max-width: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div.outer {
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div.middle {
  display: table-row;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
#a {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
#b {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#c {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
#a,
#b,
#c {
  width: 10%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 3000ms;
}
.middle.a #a,
.middle.b #b,
.middle.c #c {
  width: 80%;
  opacity: 1;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>- jsFiddle demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="middle c">
        <div class="inner" id="a">1</div>
        <div class="inner" id="b">2</div>
        <div class="inner" id="c">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```