# jquery effect to animate multiple div

Tags: jquery, animation

I have 15 divs in 3 rows, like 5 divs in a row. I want some jquery effect like I want to click a div that div will enlarge and other div will animate to both sides of my screen and stand in a vertical line. Is this possible using just jquery? Any advice will help, thanks.

Comment: This is possible with jQuery. You could use jQuery `click()` event to trigger it and then `css()` and `animate()` methods to do the rest.

Comment: There is many ways to do that, this could even be done with Css alone.
I would use a flexbox layout, with that, you do not need to animate the divs around the target divs, then i would ass a transform scale class with JS on click.
You have to show your markupand CSS for that, nobody will do all the work for you from scratch.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405879/jquery-animate-working-in-fiddle-but-not-smooth-online

Comment: using click() event and then animate that element is easy with jquery, but i want to know how to animate other div elements clicking desired div? what would the function? thanks guys, appreciated