# How do I prevent "jumping" of a div when simultanously resizing divs?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to resize these divs so that when you click on one, the others get smaller and become hidden and the one that was clicked takes up the entire width.
However, it seems that the div that was clicked gets to 100% width before the other ones are hidden, making the div jump down and back up again on the screen.

Is there a way to avoid this?
I am new at jquery and just experimenting, I have tried lots of different versions of code but they all end up having the same issue.

```
<div>
    <div id="kg-left" class="role-container role-container-left" style="margin-left:1%;text-align: center;float: left;width: 31%;border: solid;border-width: 1px;padding: 1%;height: 138px;">
        SOME TEXT
    </div>

    <div id="kg-middle" class="role-container role-container-middle"style="margin-left:1%;margin-right:1%;text-align: center;float: left;width: 31%;border: solid;border-width: 1px;padding: 1%;height: 138px;">
        MORE TEXT
    </div>

    <div id="kg-right" class="role-container role-container-right"style="margin-right:1%;text-align: center;float: left;width: 31%;border: solid;border-width: 1px;padding: 1%;height: 138px;">
        EVEN MORE TEXT
    </div>
<div>
<div>rest of html</div>
```

last code I used:

```
var roleContainerLeft = $("#kg-left");
var roleContainerMiddle = $("#kg-middle");
var roleContainerRight = $("#kg-right");

var mainMenu = $("#site-header-menu");

var state = 'showAll';

roleContainerLeft.click(function(){
    if( state == 'showAll' ) {
        containerSpacers.slideToggle(2000);
        roleContainerMiddle.slideToggle(2000);
        roleContainerRight.slideToggle(
            2000,
            function(){
                roleContainerLeft.css( 'width', '100%');
            }
        );
        mainMenu.fadeTo( 2000, 1 );
        state = 'left';
    }
});

roleContainerMiddle.click(function(){
    if( state == 'showAll' ) {
        roleContainerLeft.addClass('shrink');
        roleContainerRight.addClass('shrink');
        $(".shrink").animate(
            {
                width: '0%',
            },
            2000,
            function(){
                $(this).hide();
            }
        );
        $(".shrink").css('margin', '0%');

        roleContainerMiddle.animate(
            {
                width: '100%',
            }, 
            2000,
            function() {
                roleContainerMiddle.css('width', '100%');
            }
        );
        roleContainerMiddle.css('margin', '0%');
        mainMenu.fadeTo( 2000, 1 );
        state = 'middle';
    }
});

roleContainerRight.click(function(){
    if( state == 'showAll' ) {
        containerSpacers.slideToggle(2000);
        roleContainerMiddle.slideToggle(2000);
        roleContainerLeft.slideToggle(
            2000,
            function(){
                roleContainerRight.css( 'width', '100%');
            }
        );
        mainMenu.fadeTo( 2000, 1 );
        state = 'right';
    }
});
```

This is just my latest experiment, I have tried using simple .slideToggle() and such but whatever I try, I keep having the "jumping" issue.
Thanks for any help, I have been banging my head against the walls for 2 days now :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405879/jquery-animate-working-in-fiddle-but-not-smooth-online/

Comment: If you put that in an answer, I'll happily accept it :)

Comment: See post; used single `click` event and handler, `.siblings()` to animate elements that were not clicked to `width` `7.5%`, clicked element `width` to `80%` ; set elements initial `width` to `30%` to evenly space elements within viewport , `overflow` to `hidden` to clip text within elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.siblings()` to decrease `width` of elements not clicked to `7.5%` , set clicked element `width` to `80%`. This should total 95%, leaving 5% of viewport width for space between elements. Set `css` `display` to `inline-block`, `overflow` to `hidden` to clip text within elements, `width` set to `30%` to evenly space the three `div` elements within viewport

```js
$("[id^=kg]").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings()
  .animate({
    width:"7.5%"
  }, 500);
  $(this).animate({
    width:"80%"
  }, 500)
})
```

```css
div[id^="kg"] {
  width: 30%;
  height: 138px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
    <div id="kg-left" class="role-container role-container-left">
        SOME TEXT
    </div>

    <div id="kg-middle" class="role-container role-container-middle">
        MORE TEXT
    </div>

    <div id="kg-right" class="role-container role-container-right">
        EVEN MORE TEXT
    </div>
<div>
<div>rest of html</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The total width of three divs exceed 100%!

width(.left) = width(.right) = width(31%) + padding(1%*2) + margin-left(1%) + border(1px*2) > 35%

width(.middle) = width(31%) + padding(1%*2) + margin(1%*2) + border(1px*2) > 35%

So, the initial status looks like this.(in chrome)
[image: the initial status]

2. How to fix the jump?
   Assume you have fixed the width problem above, all you need to do is reduce the width of middle's last status.For example.

`roleContainerMiddle.animate(
      {
        width: '90%',
        // not 100%! Because of border and padding's width!
      },
      2000,
      function() {
        roleContainerMiddle.css('width', '100%');
      }
    );`

Comment: I might have missed something but I still get the div jumping around with this solution.
Thanks for the effort though.